# Why does the compiler not schedule or eliminate instructions optimally?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

I wanted to know how good the compiler does on optimizing assignments of structs and I did some testing with surprising results. (I would like to address this question to GCC.)

In particular I was looking at the assembler the GCC 4.6.3 (-O3) (edit: I also include output for GCC 4.8.0) produces of the following code:

```
template<class T>
struct C
{
  T F[3];
  C(){}
  C(const T& t0,const T& t1,const T& t2): F{{t0},{t1},{t2}} {}
};

template<class T>
__attribute__((always_inline))
C<T>
operator+( const C<T>& l , const C<T>& r )
{
  return C<T>( l.F[0] + r.F[0] , 
           l.F[1] + r.F[1] , 
           l.F[2] + r.F[2] );
}

int main() 
{
  C<C<C<float> > > a,b,c;

  a=b+c;

  printf("%s",(const char*)&a);
}
```

Here the assembler:

```
movss   264(%rsp), %xmm0
leaq    48(%rsp), %rbx
leaq    156(%rsp), %rbp
addss   376(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 4(%rsp)

movss   260(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   372(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)

movss   256(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   368(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 12(%rsp)

movss   252(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   364(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 16(%rsp)

movss   248(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   360(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 20(%rsp)

movss   244(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   356(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 24(%rsp)

movss   240(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   352(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 28(%rsp)

movss   236(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   348(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 32(%rsp)

movss   232(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   344(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 36(%rsp)

movss   228(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   340(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 40(%rsp)

movss   224(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   336(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 44(%rsp)    // 11-th

movss   220(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   164(%rsp), %xmm14
movss   160(%rsp), %xmm15
addss   332(%rsp), %xmm0
addss   272(%rsp), %xmm15
movss   216(%rsp), %xmm1
addss   276(%rsp), %xmm14
movss   212(%rsp), %xmm2
movss   208(%rsp), %xmm3
addss   328(%rsp), %xmm1
movss   204(%rsp), %xmm4
addss   324(%rsp), %xmm2
movss   200(%rsp), %xmm5
addss   320(%rsp), %xmm3
movss   196(%rsp), %xmm6
addss   316(%rsp), %xmm4
movss   192(%rsp), %xmm7
addss   312(%rsp), %xmm5
movss   188(%rsp), %xmm8
addss   308(%rsp), %xmm6
movss   184(%rsp), %xmm9
addss   304(%rsp), %xmm7
movss   180(%rsp), %xmm10
addss   300(%rsp), %xmm8
movss   176(%rsp), %xmm11
addss   296(%rsp), %xmm9
movss   172(%rsp), %xmm12
addss   292(%rsp), %xmm10
movss   168(%rsp), %xmm13
addss   288(%rsp), %xmm11
addss   284(%rsp), %xmm12
movss   %xmm15, 384(%rsp)
addss   280(%rsp), %xmm13  // all 27 floats added
movss   %xmm14, 388(%rsp)
movss   %xmm0, 444(%rsp)
movss   44(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 448(%rsp)
movss   40(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 452(%rsp)
movss   36(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 456(%rsp)
movss   32(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 460(%rsp)
movss   28(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 464(%rsp)
movss   24(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 468(%rsp)
movss   20(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 472(%rsp)
movss   16(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 476(%rsp)
movss   12(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 480(%rsp)
movss   8(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm13, 392(%rsp)
movss   %xmm12, 396(%rsp)
movss   %xmm11, 400(%rsp)
movss   %xmm10, 404(%rsp)
movss   %xmm9, 408(%rsp)
movss   %xmm8, 412(%rsp)
movss   %xmm7, 416(%rsp)
movss   %xmm6, 420(%rsp)
movss   %xmm5, 424(%rsp)
movss   %xmm4, 428(%rsp)
movss   %xmm3, 432(%rsp)
movss   %xmm2, 436(%rsp)
movss   %xmm1, 440(%rsp)
movss   %xmm0, 484(%rsp)  // Storing of temporary finished
movq    384(%rsp), %rax   // Now begin copy temporary to destination
movss   4(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm0, 488(%rsp)
movq    %rax, 48(%rsp)
movq    392(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
movq    400(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 64(%rsp)
movq    408(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
movq    416(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 80(%rsp)
movq    424(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 88(%rsp)
movq    432(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 96(%rsp)
movq    440(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 104(%rsp)
movq    448(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 112(%rsp)
movq    456(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 120(%rsp)
movq    464(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 128(%rsp)
movq    472(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 136(%rsp)
movq    480(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 144(%rsp)
movl    488(%rsp), %eax
movl    %eax, 152(%rsp)  // Whole struct copied
.p2align 4,,10
```

The assembler shows an additional copy of the whole (nested) struct starting at the line indicated. One might say this is because the compiler has to issue the assignment (in contrast to copies which can be elided).

I repeated the experiment, this time instead of a 3-fold nested struct I used only a 2-fold nested stuct. Then the the additional copy does not happen. Here's the code for the 2nd experiment:

```
int main() 
{
  C<C<float> > a,b,c;

  a=b+c;

  printf("%s",(const char*)&a);
}
```

And the assembler:

```
    movss   80(%rsp), %xmm0
    movq    %rsp, %rdx
    movss   76(%rsp), %xmm1
    addss   128(%rsp), %xmm0
    movss   72(%rsp), %xmm2
    addss   124(%rsp), %xmm1
    movss   68(%rsp), %xmm3
    addss   120(%rsp), %xmm2
    movss   64(%rsp), %xmm4
    addss   116(%rsp), %xmm3
    movss   60(%rsp), %xmm5
    addss   112(%rsp), %xmm4
    movss   56(%rsp), %xmm6
    addss   108(%rsp), %xmm5
    movss   52(%rsp), %xmm7
    addss   104(%rsp), %xmm6
    movss   48(%rsp), %xmm8
    addss   100(%rsp), %xmm7
    addss   96(%rsp), %xmm8
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movss   %xmm2, 24(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm3, 20(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm4, 16(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm5, 12(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm6, 8(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm7, 4(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm8, (%rsp)
    movss   %xmm1, 28(%rsp)
    movss   %xmm0, 32(%rsp)
```

It is obvious that the temporary struct (to hold the result of `b+c`) could be allocated completely in the register file (9 register, xmm0-xmm8) and subsequently stored without copying it.

However the operation (addition+assignment) poses only weak data dependencies on the instructions operating on storage containers. The question I am asking is: In the 1st experiment, since the data dependencies would allow for an optimal scheduling of instructions, why does the compiler not schedule the instruction in such a way that the additional copy is not necessary, i.e. storing the result directly into the final memory address? Is there some aspect of dependency or boundary the compiler cannot look through and that effectively hinders this kind of optimization?

EDIT:

Here the assembler produced from GCC 4.8.0 (-std=c++0x -S -O3):

```
movss   264(%rsp), %xmm0
leaq    48(%rsp), %rdx
movss   260(%rsp), %xmm1
addss   376(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   256(%rsp), %xmm2
addss   372(%rsp), %xmm1
movss   252(%rsp), %xmm3
addss   368(%rsp), %xmm2
movss   248(%rsp), %xmm4
addss   364(%rsp), %xmm3
movss   244(%rsp), %xmm5
addss   360(%rsp), %xmm4
addss   356(%rsp), %xmm5
movss   196(%rsp), %xmm11
addss   308(%rsp), %xmm11
movss   %xmm0, 4(%rsp)
movss   %xmm1, 8(%rsp)
movss   %xmm2, 12(%rsp)
movss   %xmm3, 16(%rsp)
movss   %xmm4, 20(%rsp)
movss   %xmm5, 24(%rsp)
movss   240(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   236(%rsp), %xmm1
movss   232(%rsp), %xmm2
addss   352(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   228(%rsp), %xmm3
addss   348(%rsp), %xmm1
movss   224(%rsp), %xmm4
addss   344(%rsp), %xmm2
movss   220(%rsp), %xmm5
addss   340(%rsp), %xmm3
movss   216(%rsp), %xmm6
addss   336(%rsp), %xmm4
movss   212(%rsp), %xmm7
addss   332(%rsp), %xmm5
movss   208(%rsp), %xmm8
addss   328(%rsp), %xmm6
movss   204(%rsp), %xmm9
addss   324(%rsp), %xmm7
movss   200(%rsp), %xmm10
addss   320(%rsp), %xmm8
addss   316(%rsp), %xmm9
addss   312(%rsp), %xmm10
movss   %xmm11, 28(%rsp)
movss   192(%rsp), %xmm12
movss   188(%rsp), %xmm13
movss   184(%rsp), %xmm14
addss   304(%rsp), %xmm12
movss   180(%rsp), %xmm15
addss   300(%rsp), %xmm13
addss   296(%rsp), %xmm14
movss   176(%rsp), %xmm11
addss   292(%rsp), %xmm15
addss   288(%rsp), %xmm11
movss   %xmm12, 32(%rsp)
movss   %xmm13, 36(%rsp)
movss   %xmm14, 40(%rsp)
movss   %xmm15, 44(%rsp)
movss   172(%rsp), %xmm12
movss   168(%rsp), %xmm13
movss   164(%rsp), %xmm14
addss   284(%rsp), %xmm12
movss   160(%rsp), %xmm15
addss   280(%rsp), %xmm13
addss   276(%rsp), %xmm14
movss   %xmm11, 400(%rsp)
addss   272(%rsp), %xmm15
movss   %xmm12, 396(%rsp)
movss   %xmm13, 392(%rsp)
movss   %xmm14, 388(%rsp)
movss   36(%rsp), %xmm13
movss   40(%rsp), %xmm14
movss   %xmm15, 384(%rsp)
movss   32(%rsp), %xmm12
movss   44(%rsp), %xmm15
movss   %xmm15, 404(%rsp)
movss   %xmm14, 408(%rsp)
movss   %xmm13, 412(%rsp)
movss   %xmm12, 416(%rsp)
movq    384(%rsp), %rax
movss   28(%rsp), %xmm11
movss   %xmm11, 420(%rsp)
movq    %rax, 48(%rsp)
movq    392(%rsp), %rax
movss   %xmm5, 444(%rsp)
movss   %xmm4, 448(%rsp)
movss   24(%rsp), %xmm5
movq    %rax, 56(%rsp)
movss   %xmm3, 452(%rsp)
movq    400(%rsp), %rax
movss   20(%rsp), %xmm4
movss   16(%rsp), %xmm3
movss   %xmm2, 456(%rsp)
movq    %rax, 64(%rsp)
movq    408(%rsp), %rax
movss   %xmm1, 460(%rsp)
movss   12(%rsp), %xmm2
movss   8(%rsp), %xmm1
movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
movq    416(%rsp), %rax
movss   %xmm0, 464(%rsp)
movss   4(%rsp), %xmm0
movss   %xmm10, 424(%rsp)
movss   %xmm9, 428(%rsp)
movss   %xmm8, 432(%rsp)
movss   %xmm7, 436(%rsp)
movss   %xmm6, 440(%rsp)
movss   %xmm5, 468(%rsp)
movss   %xmm4, 472(%rsp)
movss   %xmm3, 476(%rsp)
movss   %xmm2, 480(%rsp)
movss   %xmm1, 484(%rsp)
movss   %xmm0, 488(%rsp)
movq    %rax, 80(%rsp)
movq    424(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 88(%rsp)
movq    432(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 96(%rsp)
movq    440(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 104(%rsp)
movq    448(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 112(%rsp)
movq    456(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 120(%rsp)
movq    464(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 128(%rsp)
movq    472(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 136(%rsp)
movq    480(%rsp), %rax
movq    %rax, 144(%rsp)
movl    488(%rsp), %eax
movl    %eax, 152(%rsp)
```

The additional copy is still there.

Comment: I'm guessing the additional complexity outweighs the benefit.

Comment: Complexity of what? The optimization part of the compiler or the final code? The final code surely not, because it would be simpler.

Comment: The optimization part of the compiler.

Comment: Never underestimate the benefits of removing stores and loads. Even if there are large and deep cache hierarchies attached, elimination redundant load/stores pays off.

Comment: GCC is open source.  Perhaps you could either propose this as an enhancement, or contribute it to the code base.  Have you contacted GCC yet, and notified them that you're posting this question?  GCC is not automatically notified when someone posts a question on Stack Overflow about their compiler, so unless someone from that project happens to wander in here, an answer doesn't seem forthcoming.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a logical guess. Can someone confirm that this is adding too much complexity? How is this optimization called in compiler technology?

Comment: The GCC Help forum is located at http://gcc.1065356.n5.nabble.com/gcc-Help-f629689.html.  I suggest that you post a copy of this question there, and link back to this post.

Comment: Optimizing code is a *hard* problem. The compiler probably does better than you can do on average (especially if you wanted the code to be maintainable), but you can certainly find examples where it does silly things. Instruction scheduling and register allocation is *the* hardest problem. 4.6.3 is quite old now, and this area had a major overhaul for 4.8.0. Perhaps you should try that?

Comment: What other compilers do?